# Why is this piece of java in android code so slow?

Tags: java, android

what is wrong in **this code**, I can't understand this code.

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v){
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.singup;
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), 
 GoogleSignInActivity.class);
            break;
     }
 }
```

Comment: It depends. Here most probable cause is your GoogleSignInActivity is slow for codes you have written

Comment: cases usually have a colon, not a semicolon

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.singup_withgoogle:  // ;=>:
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), GoogleSignInActivity.class)); //); => ));
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes the code compile, but is it faster now? ;)